# What are the rules in the UK about overflying built-up areas for fun?

Tags: noise, caa-uk-regulations

I live in North London.  It's not like we don't have a fair amount of noise pollution from the sky, with helicopters, and jets landing at LHR with a stupidly shallow glide path angle.

But in addition, quite often on a Sunday afternoon I hear this buzzing of a small propeller plane.  It often seems to circle the area quite a few times before eventually going away.  We had one today: I looked at it, and (this time) it was a small plane with two props, one on each wing.  I have no idea what type of aircraft it might have been.  It was flying low enough for the buzzing to be distinctly intrusive, and therefore affecting potentially tens of thousands of people.

It may not have been a flight simply for fun. I presume there's no way of finding out... but does anyone know what the rules are for just randomly deciding to fly over a built-up area like this for the fun of it?

PS I have friends in Cambridge and you often see small light planes overflying that town. They have a friend who owns a light aircraft, and once or twice my friends have said "oh, yes, that's Jim's plane", and have confirmed he does it for recreation.

Comment: Thanks... that appears to be a site for tracking large jets landing at LHR. I'm aware of such information but my questions not about large jets.

Comment: @mins OK... thanks... well I had a look again. I haven't quite worked out how to "go back in time" with that map thing.  Secondly, this aircraft I saw earlier circled around locally quite a few times, and I've no particular reason to think that its destination or origin was LHR, or even any big airport.  But I'll give it a few more minutes trying to work out whether it's there...

Comment: Can you give a specific time when you heard this plane? And as to `jets landing at LHR with a stupidly shallow glide path angle` None of the glide path angles at LHR are less than the standard 3°. In fact some of them require an angle as high as 5.24°. The only one I’ve ever heard of that’s higher is 5.5° at LCY.

Comment: No, I don't have a specific time, and the question is about the CAA rules, such as they may be.  As to LHR glide path angles, I don't know where you're getting your information from, but this is COMPLETELY INCORRECT.  But this particular question is not about the almost unimaginably cynical politics of BAA's and CAA's management of London airspace and their utter nonsense about noise pollution: that could be another question...!

Comment: If it's a twin then it's very possibly a traffic spotting flight out of Stapleford, they overfly traffic hot-spots and report them to radio news stations.

Comment: @Mike Rodent - The Heathrow glide slopes, ILS and PAPI angles are described in the documents at http://www.nats-uk.ead-it.com/public/index.php%3Foption=com_content&task=blogcategory&id=94&Itemid=143.html  .  This is what ATC and visiting pilots will use and they are all set at the usual 3°

Comment: @mins - your SERA comment is the correct answer, you should write it up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does anyone know what the rules are for just randomly deciding to fly
>   over a built-up area like this for the fun of it?

In UK, the master document for air regulations is [The Rules of the Air Regulations](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/uksi/2015/840/pdfs/uksi_20150840_en.pdf) (ROTAR). UK being still part of the EU, they refer to a common set of rules at the EU level, the [Standardised European Rules of the Air](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/PDF/?uri=CELEX:32012R0923&from=EN) aka *SERA* ([qui sera sera](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xZbKHDPPrrc)...)

UK ROTAR state a minimum flyover height, one for VFR, one for IFR:

> The minimum heights for VFR flights shall be those specified in
>   SERA.5005(f) and minimum levels for IFR flights shall be those
>   specified in SERA.5015(b)

and SERA says:

> **SERA.5005**:
>
> (f) Except  when  necessary  for  take-off  or  landing,  or  except 
>   by  permission  from  the  competent  authority,  a  VFR  flight shall 
>   not  be  flown:
>
> - (1) over  the  congested  areas  of  cities,  towns  or  settlements
>     or  over  an  open-air  assembly  of  persons  at  a height  less 
>     than  300  m  (1  000  ft)  above  the  highest obstacle  within  a 
>     radius  of  600  m  from  the  aircraft;
> - (2) elsewhere  than  as  specified  in  (1),  at  a  height  less 
>     than 150  m  (500  ft)  above  the  ground  or  water,  or  150  m 
>     (500  ft)  above  the  highest  obstacle  within  a  radius of 150 m 
>     (500  ft)  from  the  aircraft.

So for VFR: 150 m, but 300 m in populated areas.

> **SERA.5015**:
>
> - (2) elsewhere  than  as  specified  in  (1),  at  a  level  which 
>     is  at  least  300  m  (1  000  ft)  above  the  highest  obstacle 
>     located within  8  km  of  the  estimated  position  of  the  aircraft.

And for IFR: 300 m above obstacles.

As you see this is not very high. In addition, as you mentioned, aircraft landing or taking off will indeed fly below these minimums.

> Jets landing at LHR with a stupidly shallow glide path angle

Landing cannot be done at high angle, the proper slope is the result of two elements:

- Aircraft cannot afford a high descent speed, since the vertical rate determines how hard the landing gears will touch the runway and whether they will be damaged.
- Aircraft cannot slow down under a given speed without losing their capability to create lift. This minimum speed and the previous maximum vertical speed determine a maximum slope.

This glide slope has been chosen so that it is compatible with all sorts of aircraft approach speeds and vertical rates.

A standardized value of 3° is common. But when the approach area is limited, or when this is desirable to maintain a higher altitude a longer time to reduce noise on the ground, then this angle can be increased to 3.5 or 4.5°, or even 5.5°, this is the case for some approaches at Heathrow as @TomMcW told us.

[image]
<sup>[Source](http://www.colnbrook.info/british-airways-set-to-conduct-4-trials-for-steeper-landings-for-a380s-in-noise-reduction-push/)</sup>

Alternatively, some airports have lower angles, down to 2.5°.

Comment: Thanks, that's very interesting.  I'm absolutely amazed that, seemingly, anyone can just choose to fly over an area like North London any time, and indeed I'm surprised there aren't *more* recreational flights if that's the case... are you sure there's nothing else to prevent this activity?  Surely they can't do it at night, etc.?

Comment: Re glide paths to LHR.  This is the bane of my life and I am not alone. I have learnt more than I need to about the murky politics of this and the point about me is that I live 15 miles ("as the plane lands") from touchdown at LHR.  The sine of 3 deg is 0.0523 which therefore means planes should be 0.79 miles above my house minimum.  I claim that this is NOT THE CASE.  BAA and CAA have for decades indulged in this fiction according to which noise from jets landing at LHR only "significantly" affects a couple of miles around the airport. NONSENSE.

Comment: More on the politics: BAA/CAA cannot ever admit the reality about noise pollution from jets landing at LHR, because that would then mean there would have to be serious efforts and regulations to "share the misery" evenly over the whole of the "catchment" area for LHR.  For this reason planes are still concentrated into "corridors" in arbitrary fashion, and moreover those corridors could be changed at any time.  Only a Third World country would tolerate the amount of noise pollution which Londoners routinely take for granted.

Comment: @mikerodent: Yes this can be done at night, unless there is a curfew. But I believe curfews are for airport landing/takeoff, not for just flying around. This can even be done under "[VFR at night](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Night_VFR)" rules (no specific navigation instrument required). If you ask me, yes this is abusive.

Comment: Yes, and it's not just the noise... VFR, in such a congested airspace as London, with innumerable helicopters, etc. As I say this appearance of a light plane is very infrequent currently, but if this ever changed I would be seriously concerned about the possible consequences of a crash in such a densely populated area.  I'm pretty astonished.

Comment: "anyone can just choose to fly over an area like North London any time" - it depends which part of North London.  Here's an airspace chart for that area - http://nats.aero/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/Southern-England_Ed40_v2_Standard.jpg - In the London and London City CTAs you'd need a zone clearance from Air Traffic.  Around Lippets Hill you'd expect a minimum safe altitude of 1500 feet and a ceiling of 2500 without a clearance into the TMA.  You may be seeing light aircraft flying in and out of Stapleford and Elstree....

Comment: ... also, there is this: "SERA.3105  Minimum  heights
Except when necessary for take-off or landing,  or except by permission from the competent authority, aircraft shall not be flown over the congested areas of cities, towns or settlements or over an open-air assembly of persons, unless at such a height as will permit, IN THE EVENT OF AN EMERGENCY ARISING, A LANDING  TO BE MADE WITHOUT UNDUE HAZARD TO PERSONS OR PROPERTY ON THE SURFACE. The minimum heights for VFR flights shall be those specified in SERA.5005(f) and minimum levels for IFR flights shall be those specified in SERA.5051(b)"

Comment: @Mike Rodent - there are arguments against your claim that the glide slopes being used are not those that are published but I think it would have to take place in chat rather than here, and probably wouldn't change anyone's mind.  BTW, I spent some years living in Richmond so I'm familiar with the noise levels on final :)

Comment: @DaveGremlin: How is SERA.3105 applicable to UK?

Comment: @mins  The old CAA ANO Rule 5 (the low flying rules) had a requirement that an aircraft should be able to 'glide clear' of built up areas etc.  SERA 3105 replaces this with the 'landing without undue hazard' paragraph.  SERA came in as part of the change from the JAA to the EASA and is replacing (slowly and with some exclusions) the previous UK Rules of the Air.  Chapter and verse is in this document: https://www.caa.co.uk/uploadedFiles/CAA/Content/Standard_Content/Commercial_industry/Airspace/Rules_of_the_air/Files/20171012SERAABC_ANO_PermissionsExemptions_ROTA2015Consolidation.pdf

Answer (score 1):

There are two types of rules I'm aware of that apply here:

1. [Low flying prohibitions](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/uksi/2007/734/schedule/1/crossheading/low-flying-rule/made?view=plain). These include the 1,000 feet rule and the land clear rule (a.k.a. the glide clear rule). In a built up area you must be 1,000ft above the highest obstacle and able to glide clear of the built up area in the event of **a** power-unit (engine) failure. If you have more than one power unit (like the multi-engine you mentioned), then you can continue flying with a single engine failure and I suspect that removes the need for glide clear.
2. Controlled airspace. North London is covered by controlled airspace from the surface up, so even if complying with the rule above you still need permission from air traffic control to fly there. Here's a diagram of the airspace over London, which includes TMZ, CTR, CTA and TMA (all different types of controlled airspace, all requiring permission):

[image]

Unless you in an emergency, flying into controlled airspace without permission (clearance) will get you into a world of trouble, anywhere from a stern phone call or retraining to getting your license rescinded depending on location and circumstances.

While most private pilots avoid London, there's nothing to stop you asking for a "zone transit" and if they aren't too busy they might even say yes. [Here's a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=50mS8L1cjs8) of a private pilot getting permission to fly right over North London at 2,000ft. Incidentally it's a twin engine like the one you mentioned. He's on his way somewhere and clearly experienced, so more likely to get a clearance.

Without clearance you could possibly still fly over some of North London - down to Finchley or thereabouts. Without a multi-engine aircraft you could argue you're able to glide to Totteridge Common. Here's the edge of the airspace for reference:

[image]